# What direction did the astronaut escape to?

Tags: the-wandering-earth-2

In the last part of *The Wandering Earth 2*, many small Earth spaceships approach the moon through a cloud of lunar debris. Multiple of them are destroyed due to colliding with those rocks, so it's extremely risky to get there.

Toward the end, astronaut

> Liu Peiqiang is stranded on the moon and needs to leave before a couple hundred atomic bombs blow up.

He manages to board an escape craft

> actually, an old Russian lunar landing module

and lifts off, apparently to safety (presumably to the space station).

Strangely, the lethal danger posed by the debris field around much of the moon does not seem to play a role, even though his escape vehicle was probably less maneuverable than the spacecraft on which the humans had previously arrived.

**Was that just an oversight or did it make any sense in the story, such as like his destination being mentioned as located in a direction where he wouldn't have to cross the debris field?**